# Print single and double quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, escaping

Trying to print a word inside single and double quotes.

So I want to print something like

***' "That's my word" '***

I want that the single and double quote get printed. But not sure how to do it
I tried using backslash, but not working, so clearly I am using wrong

`puts " \'"That's my word"\' "`

Comment: Simply escape both `puts "\'\"That's my word\"\'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the [Non-Interpolable String Literal](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-25q-3A+Non-Interpolable+String+Literals)

You can print single-quoted strings without complicated escapes using any matching delimiter with `%q`. For example:

```
puts %q('"That's my word"')
```

This will print what you want to standard output without issue:

> ```
>  '"That's my word"'
> ```

Internally, the String is stored as an escaped, double-quoted String. You can see this representation with the [String#inspect](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-inspect) or [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p) methods. For example:

```
p %q('"That's my word"')
#=> "'\"That's my word\"'"
```

Other related [literals](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) that [allow interpolation](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-25+and+-25Q-3A+Interpolable+String+Literals) such as `%` and `%Q` are also available if you need them.

Comment: The escaped double-quoted representation is created by `inspect`. Internally, strings are stored as a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is some syntax in ruby that can escape character, whether its `'` or `"`

## Heredoc

> You start with the symbol <<-, then a word that represents the name for this heredoc, then the heredoc contents, then you close the heredoc with that some word on its own line.

```rb
content = <<-HEREDOC
some string with ' and "
HEREDOC
puts content
```

## Strip

Or you want use `%q` oneline code

```rb
puts %q(some string with ' and ")
```

Choose which one of your favorite syntax. Ruby has many way to work with ;)

Comment: If you also need parentheses in the string then you can use something else after the %q: `%q[some string with ' and " and a smiley :)]`